# Socket.io error handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am having a problem with Socket.IO.

I am trying to reconnect the socket after the socket errors but it won't reconnect. Here is the code:

```
socket = io.connect(host, options);
socket.on('connect', this.onConnect);
socket.on('error', function() {
    //here i change options
    socket = io.connect(host, options);
});
```

Why it doesn't it create the new connection? (The host and port are being kept constant and it works for the first connection).

Comment: 1) What is the `error` event? 2) How do you know that it is not creating new connection? 3) Obviously you have to set all event handlers one more time when you are creating new connection, are you doing that?

Comment: 1) "error" is default socket.io event (https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing) 2)new connection don't logged 3) yes, I do

Comment: Logged were? On server side? Or client side?

Comment: both server and client side

Comment: You have to show us more code of both client and server.

Comment: Am having exact same issue, have you been able to solve it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try adding the option `{ 'force new connection': true }` to `io.connect`. It sounds like it isn't retrying the connection.

Socket IO won't reconnect to a host that it has already tried, unless you specify this option.

Here is a snippet with the options hash specified in-line:

```
io.connect(host, {
  'force new connection': true
});
```

You can learn more about the options here: https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO